# how to access value from hash based on key value

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have following hash

```
hash = {
   "some value": "abc",
   "other value": "dcd"
}
```

The key value is coming from an object `Test` and I can access it as `Test.key`

I am trying to access hash value from the key which is coming from Test.key. I tried to access the key value from hash `hash[:Test.key]` but that returns `NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'key' for :activity:Symbol`

How could i access the hash value?

Comment: `Test.key.class` is central to the question. Please edit to give `Test.key`'s class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby uses `Object#eql?` method to compare hash keys. If `Test.key` is a `String` and the hash key is a `Symbol`, you need to convert it to a `Symbol`.

Instead of using `hash[Test.key]`, use `hash[Test.key.to_sym]`.

See also [`Object#eql?`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) and [`Hash`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html).

Comment: yep accepted it. it was asking me to wait for 5 mins :)